# Docker-compose node express container doesn't show error logs and restart continuously

Tags: express, docker-compose

I am trying to make nginx, node express work on the container by using docker compose.

But problem is **express container doesn't show any error log why it is died**.

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  proxy:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: proxy
    ports: 
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    restart: "unless-stopped"  
  express:
    build:
      context: ./server
    container_name: express
    expose:
      - "3000"
    volumes:
      - ./source:/source
      - /source/node_modules
    restart: "unless-stopped"
```

This is my `directory structure`.

source directory, i move all files and directories from [express-generator](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) outputs.

[image]

This is my `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM node:12

COPY package*.json /source/
WORKDIR /source
RUN npm install

CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

This is my package.json

```
 {
  "name": "docker_web_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "sjk5766",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1"
  }
}
```

When i did `docker ps` after `docker-compose up -d`, result is like below.
[image]

When i did `docker logs express,` there is nothing i can see.

I really wanna know what is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your express application is running fine without docker.

you can change your Dockerfile as below

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /source

COPY . .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

COPY command will copy your local directory code to /server directory in docker
try docker-compose file as below

```
version: '3'
services:
  proxy:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: proxy
    ports: 
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    networks:
      - test_bridge
    restart: "unless-stopped"
  express:
    build: ./server
    container_name: express
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - test_bridge
networks:
  test_bridge:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: is it running without docker...like localhost:3000

Comment: i am confused. how does it work without docker..? all is described in docker-compose.yml or Dockerfile

Comment: you have two option..if nodejs is installed locally you can test it locally...by running command 1. npm install 2.node app.js then check on which port it is running..second option is..without using nginx just build docker image from express code Dockerfile and then run container 1. cd ./server 2.docker build -t image_name .   3.docker run -itd -p 3000:3000 image_name

Comment: i thought this problem is from docker setting, but is is from app.js source. thanks you save my time.